# React unit testing conditional query

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, apollo-client, react-testing-library

My component receives prop and make an apollo query based on that `Component.tsx`

```
// Component.tsx
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({ id, skipCondition }) => {
  const [displayLink, setDisplayLink] = React.useState(false);

  const { error, refetch } = useQuery(GET_LINK_BY_ID, {
     variables: { id },
     skip: skipCondition === 'N', // condition to skip the query
     onCompleted: (data) => {
       setDisplayLink(...)
     }
  })
  return <>
     {displayLink && <Link to="/test">Test link</Link>}
  </>
}
```

How can I create Unit Test for cases it skips the query, calls the query and show the *link* on template? Appreciate your helps.

Comment: Where does the `useQuery` come from? What testing library are you using? `enzyme` or RTL?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I'm using `@apollo/client` and `RTL`, will update the question

Comment: Did you read https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#example?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I've tried that but not know how to test conditional case